# How to use parameter name instead of USERNAME()

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is any way to use parameters instead of `USERNAME()` in RLS into Power BI ?

Like -

```
[Column Name] = <{Parameter Name}>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Are you trying to use RLS for a different purpose?

Comment: You can use customdata()